Is there an xjc argument '-nexclude' equivalent in jaxb-maven-plugin
I'm replacing cxf-codegen-plugin with jaxb-maven-plugin. While using the cxf-codegen-plugin, they were using -nexclude argument to exclude certain package in a namespace from generating. I'm trying to find an equivalent or a way to achieve that while using jaxb-maven-plugin. Any help is greatly appreciated!
sample code using cxf-codegen-plugin
 <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>TestGeneration</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <configuration>
            <wsdlOptions>
              <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${wsdl.dir}/test.wsdl</wsdl>
                <extraargs>
                  <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                  <extraarg>
                    http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader=com.test.myproject.common.messageHeader
                  </extraarg>
                  <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                  <extraarg>
                    http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#=om.test.myproject.common.xmldsig
                  </extraarg>
                </extraargs>
              </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
                    

I couldn't find an equivalent way of doing it using
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.0.3</version>


What does the -nexclude arguments ? You can fill in an issue in jaxb-tools repository if needed. Generating java from WSDL will not generate the "service" interface by the way
